# Classical limit and Drinfelds realization of quantum groups

Tags: qa.quantum-algebra

Let 
$$\hat{\mathfrak{g}}=\mathfrak{g}\otimes\mathbb{C}[t,t^{-1}]\oplus\mathbb{C}c\oplus\mathbb{C}d$$ 
be untwisted affine Lie algebra (as defined in V.G.Kac, *Infinite-Dimensional Lie Algebras*, 3d ed. Cambridge University Press, 1990). For $x\in\mathfrak{g}$ we can define series
$$x(z):=\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}x(k)z^k:=\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}x\otimes t^{k}.$$

Lusztig proved that, roughly speaking, classsical limit $q\to 1$ of quantum affine algebra $U_{q}(\hat{\mathfrak{g}})$ is universal enveloping algebra $U(\hat{\mathfrak{g}})$ and that Chevalley generators of $\hat{\mathfrak{g}}$, $e_i, f_i$, $i=0,1,...,n$, correspond to Chevalley generators of $U_{q}(\hat{\mathfrak{g}})$, $e_i, f_i$, $i=0,1,...,n$. Precise formulation (and proof) can be seen for example in J.Hong, S.-J. Kang,  *Introduction to quantum groups and crystal bases*, AMS, 2002.

Drinfeld found realization of quantum affine algebras $U_{q}(\hat{\mathfrak{g}})$ (here is one article about it http://arxiv.org/abs/q-alg/9610035) in terms of generators $x_{i}^{\pm}(k), a_{i}(l), K_{i}^{\pm 1}, \gamma^{\pm 1/2}, q^{\pm d}$, $i=1,2,...,n$, $k,l\in\mathbb{Z},l\neq 0$.
Classical limit $q\to 1$ of Drinfeld generators $x_{i}^{\pm}(0)\in U_{q}(\hat{\mathfrak{g}})$ are Chevalley generators $e_{i}, f_{i}\in \hat{\mathfrak{g}}\subset U(\hat{\mathfrak{g}})$ for every $i=1,2,...,n$.

My question is following:

Is classical limit of Drinfeld generators $x_{i}^{\pm}(k)\in U_{q}(\hat{\mathfrak{g}})$, $k\in\mathbb{Z}$, $i=1,2,...,n$, equal to elements $e_{i}(k), f_{i}(k)\in \hat{\mathfrak{g}}\subset U(\hat{\mathfrak{g}})$? In other words, is subalgebra of 
$U(\hat{\mathfrak{g}})$ generated by elements $e_{i}(k)$ (or $f_{i}(k)$), $k\in\mathbb{Z}$, $i=1,2,...,n$, classical limit of subalgebra of $U_{q}(\hat{\mathfrak{g}})$ generated by elements $x_{i}^{+}(k)$ ($x_{i}^{-}(k)$), $k\in\mathbb{Z}$, $i=1,2,...,n$?

**Edit**
Classical limit of Drinfelds relations for 
$U_{q}(\hat{\mathfrak{sl}}_{n})$ 
should give corresponding relations in Lie algebra 
$\hat{\mathfrak{sl}}_{n}$, 
but:

In quantum algebra $U_{q}(\hat{\mathfrak{sl}}_{n})$ we have relation (Drinfelds realization)
$$(z_{1}-q^{2}z_{2})x_{i}^{+}(z_{1})x_{i}^{+}(z_{2})=(q^{2}z_{1}-z_{2})x_{i}^{+}(z_{2})x_{i}^{+}(z_{1}).$$
If classical limit of $x_{i}^{+}(z)$ is $e_{i}(z)$, then the classical limit of the above relation would give
$$(z_{1}-z_{2})[e_{i}(z_{1}),e_{i}(z_{2})]=0.$$
But in algebra $U(\hat{\mathfrak{sl}}_{n})$ should hold
$$[e_{i}(z_{1}),e_{i}(z_{2})]=0.$$

Comment: Not sure, but .......... please take into acount that e(z) contain only positive powers of z ! , it might be that it will imply what you want.... sorry at the moment I did not do all these for quite long time..

Comment: Yep, it seems it work:  C[[z1,z2]] does not have zero divisors that it why we can cancel (z1-z2). It is important that we work with "positive currents" here - i.e. x(z), e(z) contain only z^k for k>=0

Comment: x(z) and e(z) contain all integer powers of z:
$$x_{i}^{+}(z)\in U_{q}(\hat{\mathfrak{g}})[[z^{\pm 1}]]$$
and
$$e_{i}(z)\in \hat{\mathfrak{g}}[[z^{\pm 1}]].$$

Comment: Neph, I am not sure, but as far as I remember  to work with RLL=LLR and to make this limit it seems it is necessary to work with positive currents and negative currents separately. And to see that x^{+-} is limit of corresponding e^{+-}.   For example this work by my coursemate  http://arxiv.org/abs/q-alg/9704012 treats the case of the Yangian (only positive currents vs Yangian double - Z-currents). See formulas (*) page 6. 

Answer (score 2):

It is more like comment, but seems too long.

I would say yes. I cannot give precise reference, but by all the idealogy it is yes. Or you see some "underwater stones" - problems  ?

Ideas are like this:
If you start with RLL=LLR description, then you need to make "Gauss" or "tringular" decomposition of L = LowTriangular*D*UpperTrianular to extract Drinfeld's currents.

In the classical limit "everything" takes the form  A = A_{cl} + O(h).
Now if you take  L = L_{cl} , Triangular = Triangular_{cla} + O(h)

**The simple fact that should hint that the "yes" answer is the following.**
So the decomponsition L = LowTriangular*D*UpperTrianular in classical limit
corresponds to L_{cl} = LowTriangular_{cl} + D_{cl} + UpperTrianular_{cl}

You see multiplication in the first order corresponds to addition. 
And this means that corresponding classical currents are just currents to appropriate
upper-lower triangular parts - which corresponds to x(z).

Comment: I edited my question by adding a comment in which is described what bothers me. Probably I'm missing something but I don't know what. Thank you for responce.